# Add class active to static menu

Tags: menus, pages, css

I have a static main menu, but I'd like to add the class 'active' to the menu item in the nav if it is the page, or a child of that page.

I imagine it to be a series of something like: if ( $post->post_parent == '1' ) { add_class 'active' }

Can this be done with Wordpress?

```
            <a class="item" href="/index.php">
                <i class="home icon"></i> Home
            </a>
            <a class="item" href="/about-us">
                <i class="doctor icon"></i> About Us
            </a>
            <a class="item" href="/how-do-i">
                <i class="help icon"></i> How Do I
            </a>
            <a class="item" href="/services">
                <i class="info icon"></i> Our Services
            </a>

            <a class="item" href="/do-it-online">
                <i class="user icon"></i> Do It Online
            </a>
            <a class="item" href="/contact-us">
                <i class="mail icon"></i> Contact Us
            </a>
        </nav>
```

Comment: You are looking for [is_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page). But can you explain why you hardcode the menu?

Comment: Partly lack of knowledge of how to do it any other way, partly because I wanted to have the different icons for each page. If you can suggest a better way, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1):

What you'll need to do is use [`get_ancestors()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors). Pass `get_ancestors()` your current page ID, and then search the resulting array for the menu item ID. If the menu item ID is in the array, set the class to active.